# Delete a Node from the Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to delete a Node from a Linked List ! my linked list has the following data stored in it.

```
aa 1 1 1 1
bb 2 2 2 2
cc 3 3 3 3
```

i am using the Java code and my code is

```
Node p=first;

for(Node c=first;c!=null;c=c.next){

    if(c.data.startsWith(key)){
       if(c.next==null){

       }
       else{
           p=c;
       }

       if(c==first){
           first=first.next;
       }
       else{
           p.next=c.next;
       }
    }
}
```

I am getting a problem that this code only deletes the data i.e cc 3 3 3 3 correctly. I want to that that what is the problem in my code so that i can able to delete the data i want to delete!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I... don't understand? What is the problem?

Comment: Here's a magic trick that will help you solve this problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger

Comment: How is the linked list defined and how are you storing data in it??

Comment: @DoorKnob Sir this code only deletes the last data correctly but it is unable to delete the rest of data I mean it is not accessing the data other than that of last data

Comment: What is the value of 'key' that you're passing here? You can use the debugger of any IDE to figure out what is happening or if not possible, just System.out.println statements temporarily

Comment: @Extreme Coders Sir I am inserting the data with this code
Node newNode=new Node(id);
        newNode.next=first;
        first=newNode;

Comment: @chetter Hummin I am passing the first two letters as key like aa=key cc=key etc

Comment: You are changing the first Node with every new Node insertion.

Answer (score 1):

You need this as the last line of your loop:

```
p = c;
```

You also need to eliminate the test on whether `c.next == null`. It's irrelevant to deleting the node when you have found the key.

The entire loop should be:

```
for(Node c = first, p = null; c != null; p = c, c = c.next){

    if (c.data.startsWith(key)) {
       if (p == null) {
           first = c.next;
       } else {
           p.next = c.next;
       }
       break;
    }
    p = c;
}
```

Comment: Now it only deletes the last node all the time without checking the key

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need this bit of code:

```
  if(c==first){
       first=first.next;
   }
   else{
       p.next=c.next;
   }
```

Your loop is already moving to the next node.  This code just causes you to skip every other node.  Perhaps that's why you aren't finding the key.

Comment: Its Still not working i have removed the code you asked me but the problem is that my code only deletes the last node, but i need to delete the node i wish with the help of key i am passing

Comment: That's because you only set p if it doesn't start with the key which means that you'll always delete the last node that doesn't match the key.  You want to set p in the if block (not the else block) so that p  stays set to the node that matches the key

Comment: And initialize p to NULL.  At the end of the loop p will be NULL or will point to the node that matches the key

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
Node lastNode = null;

// Traverse all nodes in the list
for (Node node = first; node != null; node = node.next) {

    // Check for node to delete
    if (node.data.startsWith(key)) {
       if (lastNode != null) {
           // directly link last node with next node to remove node
           lastNode.next = node.next;
       } else {
           // if the node to delete is the first node, update first node
           first = node.next;
       }
       // remember last node
       lastNode = node;
    }
}
```